# how to pattern match, execute a function then pattern match on the executed function to execute another function

Tags: recursion, ocaml

I'm suppose to write a function that copies elements in a array from one place to the other. copy_obj is the function doing that. now I am given a list of pointers that represents the locations of elements i need to copy therefore I need to apply the function copy_obj on each elements in the list with the address of the free location where I should start to copy. In my code it is f.

Considering that the function copy_obj returns a pair of addresses, and one is the updated value of free, I need to use to call recursively the function on other elements on the list.

below is the code I wrote, it compiles but I'am having a warning at `| h::tl -> copy_obj f h` saying this "expression should have type unit"

what can I do to arrange that?

```
let rec funct f myList =
  match myList with
  | [] -> f
  | h::tl-> 
      copy_obj f h;
      match (copy_obj f h) with
      | (free_n,addr_n) -> funct free_n tl
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be another student writing Copy GC. :-)

Expression `e1; e2` is to execute `e1` and `e2` sequentially, and normally `e1`'s return type is expected to be `unit`, which means "returns nothing special". If `e1` is an expression whose type is other than `unit`, OCaml compiler emits a warning: "expression should have type unit", since it is possible that you compute something meaningful by `e1` but you throw it away. It is sometimes a good indication of possible bugs.

In your case, `copy_obj f h` returns a tuple, probably `(int * int)`, and it is not `unit`. Therefore you got the warning. If you really ok to discard the compuation result you must write `ignore (copy_obj f h)`, where `ignore : 'a -> unit`.

You called `copy_obj f h` twice, which seems very strange. Without the definition of the function we cannot tell 100% sure but I guess you do not need the first call:

```
let rec funct f myList =
  match myList with
  | [] -> f
  | h::tl-> 
      match copy_obj f h with
      | (free_n,addr_n) -> funct free_n tl
```

If you are implementing Copy GC and if `copy_obj` copies an object `h` to a free slot somewhere available using side effect, calling the function twice here stores `h` twice. It would be a serious bug for a GC algorithm. And the warning actually tries to help you at this exact point!!

One more thing. `match` is not the only way to deconstruct your value. `let` can also extract the elements of your tuple. Normally we write like:

```
let rec funct f myList =
  match myList with
  | [] -> f
  | h::tl-> 
      let (free_n, addr_n) = copy_obj f h in
      funct free_n tl
```

Or you can simply write `funct (fst (copy_obj f h)) tl`.

Comment: Thank you so much this was very helpful, I struggled a lot with that problem