# How to pattern match execute a fuction and return a value in ocaml

Tags: ocaml

I have a function, I need to pattern match on another function to get two values. One need to be used in  one function the other needs to be returned as output.

```
let myf A=
    match (Functio A) with
    |(frr,adll) -> funct frr 45
```

I need to execute the function funct and return adll as the output of the function myf. How can I do that?

Comment: Hey, I answered you about this already!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27417880/how-to-pattern-match-execute-a-function-then-pattern-match-on-the-executed-func

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking what you say at face value, the following code will do what you want I think:

```
let myf a =
    let (frr, adll) = functio a in
    funct frr 45;
    adll
```

You may still have typing problems depending on what `funct` returns.

Note that you can replace a `match` that has only one alternative with just a `let`.

Also note that names beginning with an upper case letter are reserved for certain specific uses (such as value constructors). So you can't have a function named `Functio` or a parameter named `A`.